# Hedgehog of spininess $κ$ is an absolute retract?

Tags: set-theory, gn.general-topology, descriptive-set-theory

Let $κ$ be an infinite cardinal, $S$ a set of cardinality $κ$, and let
$I = [0, 1]$ be the closed unit interval. Define an equivalence
relation $E$ on $I × S$ by $(x,α) E (y,β)$ if either $x = 0 = y$
or $(x,α) = (y,β)$. Let $H(κ)$ be the set of all equivalence
classes of $E$; in other words, $H(κ)$ is the quotient set obtained from $I ×S$ by collapsing the subset ${0}×S$ to a point.
For each $x ∈ I$ and each $α ∈ S$, $(x,α)$ denotes the element
of $H(κ)$ corresponding to $(x,α) ∈ I × S$.  The topology induced from the metric $d$ on $H(κ)$ defined by
$d((x,α),(y,β))=|x − y|$ if $α = β$, and $d((x,α),(y,β))=
x + y$ if $α\not=β$.
The set $H(κ)$ with this topology is called the hedgehog
of spininess $κ$ and is often denoted by $J(κ)$.
The space   is a complete, non-compact, metric space
of weight $κ$.

A topological space $X$ is an absolute retract  for metrizable spaces $(M)$
provided that it is in $(M)$ and is a retract of each space $Y$ in
$(M)$ of which it is embedded as a closed subset.

${\bf Question.}$ Is the hedgehog $J(κ)$ of spininess $κ$ an absolute retract ?

Comment: Yes. It suffices for it to be an absolute extensor. In fact it's an absolute extensor for collectionwise normal spaces (and even characterises this property). This is an exercise in Engelking (see pg.337).

Comment: Thanks! It really is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is positive because the hedgehog $J(κ)$ is $AE$.